# Redux middleware not dispatching new actions

Tags: redux

I'm creating a Redux middleware that listens for a specific action. If that action type matches what I'm looking for, I want to dispatch another action. The reason for this is because I have different components with some shared functionality, so I want to update actions to have similar types, but different payloads (term), like so:

```
const updateActions = store => next => action => {
    console.log(action);
    if (action.type === 'UNIQUE_ACTION_A') {
        return next({ type: 'NEW_ACTION', term: 'new_action_a_test' });
    } else if (action.type === 'UNIQUE_ACTION_B') {
        return next({
            type: 'NEW_ACTION',
            term: 'new_action_b_test'
        });
    }
    return next(action);
};

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, updateActions))
);
```

The problem I'm having is that these actions are not dispatching. When I console.log all actions, they continue to run as normal, rather than dispatching the new actions. It's as if the call to dispatch these actions are just being ignored. What am I doing incorrectly here? Thanks!

Comment: And do you get that `console.log` at the top?

Comment: @Krasimir yes. it's logging every single action, so that's how I'm seeing that it's ignoring the actions that I'd like to dispatch.

Comment: I don't think that you'll see `NEW_ACTION` logged out because that is not going through the same function. It gets sent to the reducer. Can you try and place console.log in your reducer and see if you get `NEW_ACTION` instead of `UNIQUE_ACTION_A` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between `next` and `dispatch` inside middleware.  `dispatch` sends an action to the very start of the dispatch chain, which will cause it to run through all the middleware in the pipeline.  `next` sends it to the *next* middleware after this one, and eventually to the reducers.  By calling `next({type : "NEW_ACTION"})`, you're sending it to the next middleware, and this middleware will never see `"NEW_ACTION"`.

Also see [the Redux FAQ entry on `next` vs `dispatch` in middleware](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-middleware-chains).

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated to use `store.dispatch({ type: 'NEW_ACTION', term: 'new_action_a_test' })`, rather than `next`, but am getting a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error because it produces an infinite loop. Is there a way to work with `dispatch` without running into an infinite loop?

Comment: You must have an issue with your logic such that you're _always_ dispatching this new action, instead of only conditionally.  You'll need to fix your logic so that it only dispatches the new action under certain conditions, and those conditions don't repeat.

Comment: Yes! You are correct. There was a problem in the logic of my working codebase (not in this example above). I was checking for and setting the action type to be the same, which would cause the loop. Based on the this example above, it would not run into a loop because it sets the type to be different after it matches once. Thanks Mark!